# open api error: request should have required property '.headers' - docker

Tags: node.js, docker, openapi, pm2

My nodejs app has an open-api.yaml file and [express-openapi-validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-openapi-validate) validator. I'm doing a POST request which is  working and the api validator doesn't return any errors:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:33004/my-app/settings' --data-raw '{"serials":["1234","2355"]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

In my open-api.yaml I have:

```
openapi: '3.0.0'
servers:
 - url: 'http://{host}/my-app'
   variables:
     host:
     enum:
       - 'localhost'
       ....
...
paths:
    /settings:
      ...
      post:
        tags:
          - 'settings'
        operationId: 'postSettings'
        requestBody:
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  serials:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      type: string
...
```

Then I tried dockerizing my app - created a docker container, and ran it inside with the pm2-runtime. However, when I send the same request to the docker container when the app is running in it, I get `error while validating request: request should have required property '.headers'` . I have no property '.headers' mentioned in the open-api.yaml file.

I tried removing the validator middleware, and the request went through just fine. Can you help me understand what is the validator complaining about?

EDIT:

I managed to find the error object:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dataPath": "",
      "keyword": "required",
      "message": "should have required property '.headers'",
      "params": {
        "missingProperty": ".headers"
      },
      "schemaPath": "#/required"
    }
  ],
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "statusCode": 400
}
```

needless to say I have no required headers property...

Comment: Try adding `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to your curl command. Does this help?

Comment: Edited my question, the curl also included this header, just forgot to add it here in the question. It doesn't help...

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but YAML indentation is off - e.g. `tags`, `operationId` and `requestBody` must be inside `post`, not alongside it. Try validating your YAML in https://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: copy-pasta indentation problems, the format is fine in the code

Comment: Same problem or probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656096/openapi-request-should-have-required-property-body

Comment: Still happening with Node 18 and generator 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference if others come here for this problem:

I finally found the issue: I was using `FROM node:alpine` in my Dockerfile, which indicates the latest version of node. However, my application was running on node 10.18.1

Once I changed to `FROM:node:10.18.1-alpine` the issue was resolved.

Apparently, the [express-openapi-validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-openapi-validate) plugin has some issues in the latest node module, or so it seems.

Comment: same problem, this worked for me in `v14.16.1`

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not viable forever, the latest node version supporting this is not the current LTS anymore.

Comment: I'm running Node 18.6.0 and am dead in the water with the same problem. Trying to test my API with the Node/Express combo and it's 100% no-go because every query fails with this header complaint. The server was generated by openapi-generator version 6.0.1.

Comment: Same problem for me.  It's so frustrating,  after spending days trying out swagger and having issues.  I spend another day getting openAPITools working and now I have to use Node 10?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same for all node versions <= 14 and for express-openapi-validator version <= 3.

Impossible to have the validator working with node version 16 and we were stuck to an old dev version because of it.

The solution was to migrate to express-openapi-validator v4.

The migration is explained here https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator#upgrading-from-3x

This (v3):

```
const validator = new OpenApiValidator({
  apiSpec: openApiYaml,
  operationHandlers: __dirname
})
app.use(validator)
```

becomes (v4):

```
const validator = OpenApiValidator.middleware({
  apiSpec: 'src/openapi.yaml'
})
app.use(validator)
```

The code was originally generated by https://hub.docker.com/r/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli

Answer (score 3):

Might be a little late but hopefully will be useful for others.

The problem is related to this code (this is the compiled version)

```js
...
const reqToValidate = Object.assign({}, req, { cookies: req.cookies
                    ? Object.assign({}, req.cookies, req.signedCookies) : undefined });
const valid = validator(reqToValidate);
...
```

on OpenApiValidator and the fact that Express `req` object use accessor get/set for headers, as a result Object.assign will not propagate headers information and consequenlty the `validator` function will not find the required headers properties, only rawHeaders is available.

As a quick fix I implemented the following:

```js
const validator = this.openApiValidator.validate(method, path);
return (req, res, next) => {
    const reqToValidate = Object.assign({}, req, {
        cookies: req.cookies
            ? Object.assign({}, req.cookies, req.signedCookies) : undefined
    });
   
    if (!reqToValidate.hasOwnProperty('headers')) {
        reqToValidate.headers = req.headers;
    }
    return validator(reqToValidate, res, next);
};
```

which adapts Express request and propagate all required information regarding headers.

Comment: Which file did you make this edit to?  I'm running into the same issue after generating server stub using the below command:


`./openapi-generator-cli.sh generate -i petstore.json -g nodejs-express-server -o petstore/`