# OpenAPI can't connected

Tags: node.js, openapi-generator

I'm trying to build a API base on https://github.com/coinbase/rosetta-specifications/blob/master/api.yaml specification.
Now i have run this yaml file in openapi generator for nodejs-express-server (https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/nodejs-express-server)

When i want try to access the endpoint /network/list it give me error:

```
    {
    "message": "request should have required property 'headers'",
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": ".headers",
            "message": "should have required property 'headers'",
            "errorCode": "required.openapi.validation"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have add the following header in postman: Content-Type: application/json (as specify in yaml file).

can anyone please let me know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a defect in this server; I'm stalled by it also. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420890/open-api-error-request-should-have-required-property-headers-docker

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after degrading the node version to 12.13.0

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow. Please explain why degrading would help.
As written on the [official nodejs website](https://nodejs.org/fr/blog/release/v12.22.12), node12 reached end of life in april 2022, so i'd guess it's not such a good idea.